# Do we need Web Service working experience to learn/work on WCF for web application?

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have not worked on Web Services, but now I am planning to work on WCF Services in my next web application project. Do we need to have prior working experience on Web Services to work on WCF ?

can we start learning/working on WCF directly with out working experience in Web Services ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any prior experience in web services to use WCF, though it would of course help in some situations. Having said that, WCF does have a learning curve (like everything), so you should consider going through some training, like the [excellent Pluralsight training](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/).

In addition to some sort of training, a must have resource for WCF in my opinion is [Juval Lowy's book, Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489).

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for Pluralsight training. I went through most of their WCF screen casts and they are pretty good but still I would recommend some tutorial and small hands on experience before going to these screen casts.

Comment: Added a link to Lowy's book. :)

Comment: @Brandon, thanks for directing me with plural sight training and a good book on WCF, they should be a good place for me to start with.. Thanks again..!!

Comment: No problem - WCF is a fantastic platform for building applications, and I predict it will be the future of Microsoft application development.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by Web Services? Do you mean ASP.NET Web Services (ASMX)? If so, you don't need experience with them to learn WCF.

WCF is API for creating web services (and remote services generally) so once you start learning WCF you will start learning how to create and work with web services.

Comment: Ladislav, yes it is (ASMX), thanks for your comment ("once you start learning WCF you will start learning how to create and work with web services") it helps..!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think yes.  It should not be a problem to write a WCF service even if you do not have web service development background.  At least, I did not have this experience at the beginning :). I have posted a link to good WCF book at:

[Recommended beginner's learning resources for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603662/recommended-beginners-learning-resources-for-wcf/6603900#6603900)

Comment: Thanks platon for pointing towards the right resources, good to know that you started learning WCF with out Web Services knowledge because it helps to motivate that I am not the only person :))

Comment: at some moment, one should start doing something which is absolutely new :)